# Parsing NSDictionary from NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, json, ios

`playerObject` is an `NSDictionary` from `JSONObjectWithData:options:error`.

I'm trying to update a `CoreData` entity.

```
if ([results count] > 0)
{
    newPlayer = (Player *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
} else {
    //Add a new player
    newPlayer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext];
}
//Assume these exist and are not null
newPlayer.email = [playerObject objectForKey:@"email"];
newPlayer.username = [playerObject objectForKey:@"username"];
newPlayer.continent = [playerObject objectForKey:@"continent"];

//Dates
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
newPlayer.created = [df dateFromString: [playerObject objectForKey:@"created"]];

//Optional properties
if ([[playerObject objectForKey:@"title"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
    newPlayer.title = nil;
} else {
    newPlayer.title = [[playerObject objectForKey:@"title"] stringValue];
}
```

Is there any way to make it less verbose?  Have I left myself open to any issues?

Comment: Take a look at JSRestNetworkKit and stop parsing the JSON yourself :) https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSRestNetworkKit

Comment: Looks interesting but I'd just want to use the mapping from a dictionary to CoreData entity. Would this be possible?

Comment: You mean without making requests to an API? Yes, absolutely, you would just have to make your CoreData entities inherit from JSBaseCoreDataBackedEntity and use + (id)updateOrInsertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

Comment: Excellent. I'll take a look into that then, since I'm using JSON-RPC for the web service.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([results count] > 0)
{
    newPlayer = (Player *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
} else {
    //Add a new player
    newPlayer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext];
}
```

This chunk of code could be replaced with:

```
newPlayer = (Player *)([results firstObject] ?: [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext]);
```

---

```
if ([[playerObject objectForKey:@"title"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
    newPlayer.title = nil;
} else {
    newPlayer.title = [[playerObject objectForKey:@"title"] stringValue];
}
```

This chunk of code could also be slightly better.

```
NSString *newTitle = playerObject[@"title"];
newPlayer.title = [newTitle isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? nil : [newTitle stringValue];
```

---

The last comment that I'll make is a strong recommendation that you use constants for your keys rather than literal strings.  Defined constants will auto-complete for you, which is nice, but more importantly, it will eliminate misspellings entirely.

```
static NSString * const kKey_Player = @"Player";
static NSString * const kKey_Title = @"title";
// etc.
```

Then use it as such:

```
NSString *newTitle = playerObject[kKey_Title];
```

Under the covers, this actually doesn't change in the slightest what the code does.  Even when you use string literals, a memory location is still allocated for them.  The advantage here is that you eliminate programmer mistakes.